# OpenCV: What methods or binarization techniques can be used to generally extract foregrounds on low quality and low contrast images?

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

Below are just 2 of the few cropped images that I wanted to binarize. As you can see, I just want to get the circular things from the images. Just from looking at it, one can clearly distuingished the circular objects as the foreground. I thought it was as easy to binarize it. I tried adaptice thresholding, Otsu's, Sauvola, Niblack and Wolf binarization technique. I've also tried improving their contrast before binarization but none of them works perfectly. Can anyone suggest a way or a step-by-step procedure to extract the circular things on the images below?

[image: sample01.jpg]

[image: sample02.jpg]

Comment: not quite sure but edge detection might do the trick here

Comment: "I thought it was as easy to binarize it" ... what made you think that? Try looking at it from numerical perspective (just brightness values, without seeing the image), it may help to fix your expectations. A computer can't look at it so easily. Human is operated by huge neural network, trained (among other things) for pattern recognition since birth (actually it's over-trained, easy to fool by specially prepared images), operating at level of efficiency yet to be simulated by numerical methods.

Comment: But if your inputs are like this, 2 major brightness levels with incoherent details, you may still go with Payne answer, for multiple valleys try to binarize all the possible values (start in middle?), and check the resulting binarized images for results... (if having more circles detected is more correct, it would be easy to assess success of binarization .. if you have no idea how many circles there "should" be, it's a tough one).

Answer (score 1):

Create histogram of your image and find valley which is dividing foreground and background of your image - thats your [Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1PP9.png), now you can do binarization.

After that you can simply use *open/close* operation to improve your image.

Comment: That sounds like Otsu's method

Comment: When you said "find the valley dividing fg to bg", does that mean I have to find for the lowest point in the middle of my histogram? How can I effectively and dynamically find the valley of the histogram my image? What if I have many valleys? 

btw, on what image did you get that histogram? Is it one of my attached images?

Comment: I created this histogram few month ago when i had to isolate rice from background and count them - i have done this in matlab, using like @samgak called it "Otsu's" method. [rice-img](http://agri-1.com/hatsugagenmai/image/genmai_mk.jpg), if u already tried it, im sorry for useless answer. btw circular things from your image are totally black so u shouldn't have problem to  'pick them up'.